# Find definite integral based on other definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $\int^4_{-2}f(x)dx = 3$, $\int^0_{-2}f(x)dx=10$, $\int^4_2f(x)dx=2$

Find $\int^2_0f(x)dx = -9$

and

$\int^0_2(3f(x) - 10)dx=??$

I figured out the first part is -9 since 10+2-9=3.

I thought the second part would be $3(-9)-10=-37$ since f(x) from 0 to 2 =-9 but that isn't correct.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not from $0$ to $2$ it's from $2$ to $0$. You need another minus sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int_{2}^{0}(3f(x)-10)dx=-\int_{0}^{2}(3f(x)-10)dx=-3\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx+10\int_{0}^{2}1dx=-3\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx+20.$